# Taylor or binomial expansion involving vectors

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose we have a unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$, a position vector $\mathbf r$, and a scalar $\rho$. Given that $|\mathbf{r}/\rho|\ll1$, we can expand the following expression

$$(1+2\hat{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{\rho}+\frac{\mathbf{r}^2}{\rho^2})^{-3/2}$$

up to second-order, that is,

$$1-3\hat{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{\rho}-\frac{3}{2}\frac{\mathbf{r}^2}{\rho^2}+\frac{15}{2}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{\rho})+\dots.$$

Do we use the Taylor theorem here or the binomial theorem?

For the taylor, I am not sure how to do the derivatives here, especially with the dot product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'natural' Taylor theorem, as you expand in powers of $||\bf{r}/\rho||$. Simply note that all the quantities involved here are scalars, and that by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|\hat{\bf{x}}.\frac{\bf{r}}{\rho}| \leq ||\bf{\hat{x}}|| \times ||\frac{\bf{r}}{\rho}||$.

Then you simply use the Taylor theorem that states that for $x$ close to $0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$(1+x)^a = 1 + a x + \frac{a(a-1)}{2}x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$.

So I believe the last term in your expansion should actually be $+\frac{15}{8} \left(\hat{\bf{x}}.\frac{\bf{r}}{\rho}\right)^2$ if I am correct.